# Schema Remote Review

Tags: microdata, rich-snippets, google-rich-snippets-tool

I have set up an aggregate review on my footer, pulling review data from `eKomi.co.uk`. When I pass this through the Google Structured Data tester it complains about there being an aggregate review, but no reviews.

The schema includes a 'sameAs' property which is a URL. Can I use this and point it to my store's eKomi page to make Google aware that this is where I am pulling my reviews from, and that this page contains all said reviews?

#### [Edit]

I pulling the review via `file_get_contents` then using `DOMDocument` to get the value of the review and the total number of reviewers. This information I am putting into a `span` for the aggregate review.

Instead of downloading, and creating mark-up for, hundreds of individual reviews, can I use the `sameAs` property for `AggregateReview`?

Comment: (1) Do you mean *ekomi-us.com* (instead of *ekomi.com*)? (2) How are you "pulling" the review data? Client- or server-side? (3) Which type do you use for the "aggregate review"?

Comment: @unor 1) I meant ekomi.co.uk; 2) Server-side; 3) Microdata: http://schema.org/AggregateRating

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google’s documentation of their Rich Snippet [Aggregate Review](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/146645?hl=en#aggregate) still uses the Data-vocabulary.org vocabulary, but I think it’s safe to assume that this also applies to the Schema.org vocabulary.

There it says about `count` (which would probably be [`reviewCount`](http://schema.org/reviewCount) in Schema.org):

> **Note:** Whenever you include `count`, the page must also contain review markup for each reviewed item. `count` should only include reviews on your own site.

So if Google enforces this, there is no way to have this Google Rich Snippet when the reviews are on a different place.

As an alternative, you may use the [`ratingCount` property](http://schema.org/ratingCount) (which gives the "total number of ratings" instead of "reviews").

(Note that all this only applies to Google’s Rich Snippets; using `reviewCount` in this way is totally fine from the Schema.org perspective.)

Comment: I have implemented schema's aggregateRatings with ratingCount so that the rich-snippets show `4/5 - 400 reviews` instead of `400 votes`. The rich snippets currently work, I just want to get rid of the "error" message in the testing tool.

What use is the `sameAs` property? How should it be used?

Comment: @RichardParnaby-King: Ah, then it seems the SDTT is not in line with their Rich Snippet docs. -- Regarding [`sameAs`](http://schema.org/sameAs): Only use this to link to other resources that are about (= identify) the *thing* the item is about. If you want to use it for `AggregateRating`, you may only link to resources that are about this very same aggregate rating. I know of no evidence that Google would use this property for anything.